# POST method not logging input information

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a form with 'title' and 'body' and the plan is that whenever I write something in them and submit, it should be displayed in the console.log. I tried to do it, but it gives me only this:

> {id: 0, title: "", body: "", userId: 0}

Here is my form-add.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { form } from '../forms/form-interface';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-add',
  templateUrl: './form-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-add.component.css']
})
export class FormAddComponent implements OnInit {
  private formUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  forms: form = {
    "id": 0,
    "userId": 0,
    "title": '',
    "body": ''
  };


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

      addForm() {
        fetch(this.formUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.forms.id,
            title: this.forms.title,
            body: this.forms.body,
            userId:  this.forms.userId
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
    }


  }
```

here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" routerLink = '/posts' >
    Back
    </a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Add New Form:</h2>
</div>

<div class="forms container">
<form #postForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input  
        name="title"  
        id="title" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Body</label>
      <textarea  
      name= "body" 
      id="body" 
      cols="30" 
      rows="10" 
      class="form-control"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click) = addForm()>Add</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is my form-interface:

```
export interface form  {
    "userId": number,
    "id": number,
    "title": string,
    "body": string
}
```

Comment: show `fetch` method

Comment: How can I show it? I just used the method based on angular documentation.

Comment: Use angular reactive forms way. you can learn more [here](https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/gentle-introduction-to-reactive-forms-in-angular-c3cb01b90037)

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies I have a task to do it using POST method, that's why I'm doing it that way.

Comment: @Mavinter Yes that's fine but issue is not in post, issue is you are not binding input value correctly so that's why it's empty when you console in addForm(). So for data binding you should use FormsModule or reactive forms that i gave link. Also you should first know how two way data binding works in angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(this.formUrl, {...})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

This mean: print response from server. Server can change values or provide new set of data depending of server implementation.
If you want to print request you can do it before sending http request like:

```
console.log({ id: this.forms.id, body: this.forms.body })
```